# selecting radio button in UITableviewcell in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, radio-button

Am display list of names in UITableview and I'm trying to select any one of the names by using radio button. The problem I face is I can't select the specific row of the cell, either all the rows are selected or deselected.

Code for displaying radio button in cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIButton *report_but;
int flag;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == Nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
 cell.textLabel.text = [user_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

report_but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
report_but.frame = CGRectMake(260,18,20,20);
[report_but setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (flag == 0) {
    [report_but setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_blank.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
[report_but setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[report_but addTarget:self action:@selector(radio_button:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:report_but];
return cell;
}

- (void)radio_button:(id)button
{

NSLog(@"radio button clicked");
NSLog(@"button tag %@",button);
if (flag == 0) {
    flag = 1;
}
else
    flag = 0;

[table_list reloadData];
```

}

While row 1 is selected
[image]

And I can't use didselectrowatindexpath method for this single row selection, since selecting the row should not select the radio button.

Can any one help me to select the only one row of this tableviewcell.

Comment: Instead of `flag` use an `indexPath`(NSIndexPath object) to store selected row, and check for that `indexPath` in `cellforRow` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIButton *report_but;
    if (cell == Nil) 
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         UIButton *report_but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         report_but.frame = CGRectMake(260,18,20,20);
         [report_but setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         report_but.tag = 8888;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:report_but];
    } 

    report_but = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8888];
    if (selectedIndexPath && selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row) {

    } else {

    }

}
```

and in `radio_button:`

```
- (void)radio_button:(id)button
{
     CGPoint pointInTable = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.tableView];    

     selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
     [table_list reloadData];
}
```

Comment: rather than dealing with points you may give tag of index path row to the button and get the cell of that index path. it would be more appropriate way.

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora but setting indexPath as tag won't work if a cell is added or removed or reordered.

Comment: - (void)radio_button:(id)button
{
    UIButton *senderbutton = (UIButton *)button;
    NSLog(@"button tag %ld",(long)senderbutton.tag);
} Always returns 0, as button tag. Am I doing something wrong here? @PoojaManiklalBohora

Comment: Have you set tag while creating it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: no i didn't set its tag value,@PoojaManiklalBohora, now i have set its value as report_but.tag = 0; in cellforrowatindexpath while creating its button.. again it returns 0 as its tag value.

Comment: @sathya what tag you are setting `report_but` in `cellforrowatindexpath`?

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora, yes after assigning [report_but setTag:indexPath.row]; i could get proper tag values for button while clickng

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, i set 0 as its tag value, so it went wrong... now no problem about tag value of button

Comment: @sathya then `selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: button.tag inSection:0]` and `[table_list reloadData];`

Comment: NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: senderbutton.tag inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"sel indexpath %@",selectedIndexPath);  Its returning o/p as so, sel indexpath <NSIndexPath: 0x8b8b650> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}

Comment: @sathya make `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath` as instance variable so that you can compare it in `cellforrowatindexpath` to make radiobutton selected or unselected.

Comment: @sathya happy to know you got the answer. Cheers.